# What is the value of angle x in the figure below?

Tags: geometry

For reference: (Answer: x = $115^\circ$)
[image]

My progress..Here are the main relationships I found

$K(incenter)\\ \therefore \measuredangle HGK = \beta\\\measuredangle EFB = 180 - 4\theta\\\measuredangle BEF = 180 - 4\alpha\\ \measuredangle EFB + \measuredangle BEF = 100^o\rightarrow 180-4 \theta +180-4 \alpha =100 \therefore  \boxed{\alpha +\theta = 65^o}\\\measuredangle FIE = 90^o - \frac{80}{2}=50^o = \measuredangle GIH\\ \measuredangle CKG = 90^\circ+\frac{\measuredangle CGE}{2} (by~ property)\\
\measuredangle CIE = 180 - (2\alpha + \beta)\\
\measuredangle EGF = 180 - (2\alpha + 3\theta)$

Comment: Are the points F, E, G and H free (like random points) on their respective sides (with AGHC in that order), and then I intersection point of (FH), (EG)? I don't really understand which points are fixed in the figure and which aren't. And also, is 80° the only restriction for angles? I think the construction should be detailed a bit.

Comment: The first line of your progress was confusing to me. $K$ is the incentre of $\triangle EGC$, but the claim that $KG=KC$ seems derived from that $K$ is instead the circumcentre.

Comment: @peterwhy,,you're right...KC is diferrent KG

Comment: @Nithuya..The figure is exactly as in the book and as demonstrated by MathLover is perfectly solvable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If three angle bisectors of a quadrilateral are concurrent, the fourth angle bisector is concurrent with them (see angle bisectors section [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral)). Drawing perpendicular segments to sides of quadrilateral from the point of concurrency of three angle bisectors easily shows it.

Now consider quadrilateral $ACEF$. As three angle bisectors meet at $I$, the fourth will too. In other words, $AI$ is angle bisector of $\angle BAC$.

So in $\triangle AHF$, $J$ is the incenter,

$\angle AHJ = 90^\circ - \theta - (50^\circ - \beta) ~$
(as $~\angle BAC = 100^\circ - 2 \beta$)

In $\triangle CEG$, $K$ is the incenter,

$\angle CGK = 90^\circ - \alpha - \beta$

So, $x = 180^\circ - (130^\circ - \theta - \alpha) = 115^\circ ~$ (as $~\theta + \alpha = 65^\circ$)

Comment: ,,,excellent...thankful...the bisector tip was fundamental

Comment: @petaarantes you are welcome!